# What it correct protocol for defining a test in JUnit 5

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, automated-tests

A simple question: what do I need to do to write a test that is called in JUnit driven by Maven?  I have consulted the documentation, but it appears to be wrong.  Clearly there is something I don't understand.

I defined a test like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public void class TestSet1 {

    @Test
    public void addition() {
        // ... perform test here
    }
    
}
```

I would run `mvn clean test` and get 0/0 tests run.  in a different repository it was working so I am swapping things around and through trial an error, I find that:

1. the test method must begin with 'test'
2. the `@Test` annotation is not needed

What ended up working is:

```
public class TestSet1 {

    public void testAddition() {
        // ... perform test here
    }
    
}
```

This is contrary to the documentation.  Here is the [JUnit 5 Users Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests) from which this test example was taken from.  What is the deal?   The documentation clearly says that the former should work, but it utterly failed to, and after a lot of sturm and drang I found that the rules appear to be different.  I replicated this independently on two different environments, my work computer and also my home computer.

Or is it how I have maven configured?  Below is my POM file, and if there is something wrong with that, please let me know.  Clearly it is loading JUnit 5.9.2 and the documentation is marked for JUnit 5.9.2.

UPDATE: as suggested by one answer, I have specified a version for surefire, but the result is the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.purplehillsbooks</groupId>
  <artifactId>purple</artifactId>
  <version>3.2</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the full actual test class:

```
package com.purplehillsbooks.testcase;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
public class Test3 {

    public Test3() {
    }

    public void testAddition() {
        System.out.println("Test3.testAddition has run");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void addition() {
        System.out.println("Test3.addition has run");
    }
}
```

Here is the output from running this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.purplehillsbooks.testcase.Test3
Test3.testAddition has run
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Has the means of indicating a test changed?  I am confused, and *I am probably not the only one*.

UPDATE2: I added the following to the POM

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And I now get this output:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.purplehillsbooks.testcase.Test3
Test3.addition has run
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 s - in com.purplehillsbooks.testcase.Test3
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

That is correct, but strange that this has nothing to do with JUnit, and everything to do with SureFire.

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: I just tested on one of my working projects.  `@Test` is required, and naming the method starting with "test" doesn't matter.  I think your problem is elsewhere.  Try cleaning the project manually, then rebuild the full project.  I think you have compile errors you are missing.

Comment: @markspace do you have explicit surefire config? I was able to reproduce this behaviour with no surefire config, mvn 3.8.1

Comment: No, I'm just running my default IDE.  I'm not sure why Maven or the version would make a difference.

Comment: If I run the tests in IDEA, then the pom doesn't make a difference. If I run via `mvn package`, it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this happens because you are running an older version of the `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Add this to your pom:

```
    <build>
        <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now you should see the expected behaviour.

Why the defaults are like this, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Strange how this behavior is defined by SureFire, and not JUnit.  The JUnit documentation should point you to the SureFire documentation about designating tests.  The JUnit documentation should refer exclusively to the default behavior of maven.  Thanks again for the tip.  I don't know how I would have found this otherwise.  This makes the behavior the same as the documentation, however I am tempted to use the default behavior because the fewer specific tweaks I have the better.  I am not religious about one approach or the other, but just want it to work in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your example

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    public class TestSet1 {
    
        @Test
        public addition() {
            // ... perform test here
        }
        
    }
```

You are trying to put the Test annotation on the constructor. Most likely you wanted to write a method that will test the code, but you forgot the return type, in tests it should be void.Here's what you should get:

```
@Test
void addition() {}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's a typo -- the working version has the same mistake. That's why I asked for actual code: Who knows what it really looks like!

Comment: If this is a typo, then I do not really understand how it is possible to run a test without the annotation Test (-_-)

Comment: I am so sorry.  I did do this on several projects in several environments.  I simplified it for here, copying the code from the documentation for an example because of course the real code had 5 or 6 classes involved in complicated ways.  I didn't notice that the example from documentation was missing a return type.   I am guilty of putting in an example that was not actually what I compiled, but I am quite sure that the naming must be as I discovered it to be and that this is representative.  Apologies for the typo in what I put here.

Comment: Updated with ACTUAL code